# Free Tool for reading everyone.net Webmail in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, software-rec, webmail

Does anyone know of a free tool that I can use to read my everyone.net basic webmail account in Thunderbird? If not, is there a good way for me to migrate my email out of my everyone.net account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this guide from their website:

http://www.everyone.net/pdf/everyone_thunderbird20.pdf

It has detailed instructions on how to set up Thunderbird to read your everyone.net email via either IMAP or POP3.